# How to remove HTML tags from RSS feed?

Tags: javascript, rss

I am using [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1) to extract blog entries from a [tumblr feed](http://adriennetran.tumblr.com/rss).

I have been able to pull the content, but the output comes out with the html tags as such:

`<p>I remember one day asking one of my mentors James if he ever got nervous around people. James replied, “Only when I need something from them.”</p>`

The code is simple, as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
google.load("feeds", "1");

 function initialize() {
   var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://adriennetran.tumblr.com/rss");
   feed.load(function(result) {

     if (!result.error) {
       var container = document.getElementById("feed");

       for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
         var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
         window.content = document.createTextNode(entry.content);
         container.appendChild(content);
       }
     }
   });
 }


 google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

 </script>
```

I tried writing a function to strip everything that starts with `<` as such:

```
content_array = content.split(" ");

for (i=0; i < content_array.length; i++){
    if ((content_array[i].split(""))[0] == "<"){
      content_array.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

content2 = content_array.toString();
```

But I got an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error because `content` is an `object` and not a `string` and therefore I cannot call `content.split(" ")`.

I've tried converting to a string, but this is the output from console

```
typeof(content)
> "object"

c2 = content.toString()
> "[object Text]"
```

Does anybody have any ideas on how to manipulate elements retrieved from RSS?

Comment: To be of further service could you provide a JSfiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see

```
var regExString = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig; //create reg ex and let it loop (g)
contentString = content.textContent // get text from node (no longer an object but string.

contentString = contentString.replace(regExString, "") //find all tags and delete them.
```

Comment: Good thinking! I tried that but content.toString just yields as output: " object"

WOW that is a much easier .replace tag though than that long function I wrote.

Comment: To be clear. This is the output:

`typeof(content)
"object"
c2 = content.toString()
"[object Text]"`

Comment: @Aspen Updated my code. It seems that the object is a text node. node.textContent should work magic.

Comment: I believe he is correct. Simply change `entry.content` to `entry.content.textContent`. That should also remove your HTML tags in the process. Does it?

Comment: @Makaze no it does not. Since it is a text node, it will be recognized as plain text with HTML.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Good job on the solution, then.

Comment: ahhh gotcha. I was wondering why it didn't work. Thanks!
jQuery also makes it easy, `var text = $(content).text();`
YOU ARE SUPER AWESOME MOUSER!!!! (i've spent hours trying to figure this out)

Comment: @Aspen No problemo, Never hurts to help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery included on your page, you can create a node using the HTML received from your feed and get the text from the HTML like so:

```
var html = '<p>I remember one day asking one of my mentors James if he ever got nervous around people. James replied, “Only when I need something from them.”</p>';
var text = $(html).text(); // This gets the text from any HTML code and leaves out the tags
```